# Query an XML file to extract a date-based value in C# using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I'm trying to bring some code I wrote in VB.NET on an [ASP.NET WebForms site](http://www.mississaugastreetsville.ca/) (top right) years ago up to date. What the existing site does on loading is to evaluate today's date and put it on the header on the master page (layout page in MVC). I know how to do that.

Below the date, it *may* display a short date-specific message if today is Christmas, St. Patrick's Day or any of what has become some 100+ specific dates throughout the year. I had used a `Select Case` in VB.NET, with the `Case Else` containing code defining, for example, how many days are left in summer, or until Christmas, if there is nothing defined for that specific date. It strikes me that reading the dates and setting a variable to be used in the page's HTML would be easier to manage in an XML file instead of editing it in the code behind file on my existing forms page. Here is what I have so far:

### XML Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DateInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="todayDate" type="xs:date" />
        <xs:element name="todayMsg" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### XML Data File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<KeyDates>
  <DateInfo>
    <todayDate>2014-07-29</todayDate>
    <todayMsg>First full day of holidays</todayMsg>
  </DateInfo>
  <DateInfo>
    <todayDate>2014-07-30</todayDate>
    <todayMsg>Hope it doesn't rain today</todayMsg>
  </DateInfo>
  <DateInfo>
    <todayDate>2014-07-31</todayDate>
    <todayMsg>Sorry to see the end of July</todayMsg>
  </DateInfo>
...
</KeyDates>
```

### Code on my web page that inserts todayMsg into the web page

This I have never done before, and don't know how to do in either C# or VB.NET. Can anyone help me with how to query the XML file, extract the message (if any) for today's date, and put it onto a CSHTML page, either in a paragraph or as the text of an ASP.NET label. I suspect this can't be that hard.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question will most likely be closed.  Questions on Stack Overflow typically include a code sample, what you expected to have happen, and what actually happened.  If you don't know at all how to write c#, then instead of asking someone else to do your work, you should research the internet (google, other stack overflow questions) for examples to get started.

Comment: I greatly appreciate this answer, which worked for me as soon as I added `using System.Xml.Serialization;` to the project. I would not have made this work so quickly. Why would you close this discussion? I _did_ read through many articles on the web, nor am I asking you to do my work. Thank you for teaching me a technique I did not know before.

Answer (score 1):

Cobbled this together quickly for you as a working example of how to do this.

The following will deserialize the XML into two objects (which reflects your XML layout), you can then loop through the data comparing the dates to the current date and output the message if it matches. Not the neatest example in the world, but it certainly gives you a starting point.

I would highly recommend you look into how C# works, OOP, objects, deserializing, properties etc. so you can understand how this works.

While I agree with what Erik Philips said in the comment above, I learn better myself from examples like this so thought I'd put something together :)

```
public class KeyDates
{
    [XmlElement("DateInfo")]
    public List<DateInfo> DateInfo { get; set; }
}

public class DateInfo
{
    [XmlElement("todayDate")]
    public string todayDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("todayMsg")]
    public string todayMsg { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(KeyDates));

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("F:\\Data\\Desktop\\ddd.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            KeyDates keyDates = (KeyDates)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            foreach (DateInfo dateInfo in keyDates.DateInfo)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == dateInfo.todayDate)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dateInfo.todayMsg);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer @Craig +1 but you could use an Explicit conversion by doing something like this: KeyDates keyDates = (KeyDates)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Adjustments made to my original post.